# Add duplicate rows in Python

Tags: python, tabular

Python newbie here. I have the following table:

```
Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4  
---------------------------
abc       2      45      6  
def      12       7     56  
ghi      34       0      1  
abc     122     345     67  
abc       0      45      9  
ghi      32       1     23
```

Some of the rows have duplicate text entries in Col1 that I need to add. So the output should look like:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3   Col4  
---------------------------
abc     124     435     82  
def      12       7     56  
ghi      66       1     24
```

Kindly let me know the best way to achieve this?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: What python package are you using to handle these data? What's the original format? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `df.groupby('Col1').sum()`? if you're using `pandas`. Specify `as_index=False` if you don't want `Col1` to become your new index